# Creating new rails project with jruby in 1.9 compatibility mode hangs when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

Anyone encountered this problem? I am able to create the project fine in 1.8 compatibility mode.

Here is what I am using

- Mac OSX Lion
- JRuby 1.6.4
- Java 1.6.0_31
- rvm 1.8.1

I am running the following command

```
JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9 rails new myapp
```

This goes ahead and creates all the files required for the app and then hangs at the statement.

```
run bundle install
```

When I look at Activity Monitor the java process is using up most of the cpu.

Comment: When/where/how does it hang? What are you trying to install? What OS? This is a little light on actual details--I'd consider editing it to include information.

Comment: Did you try with a current version of JRuby? I'll install the older version and check locally.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that; I have 1.6.7 installed, and the [download page](http://jruby.org/download) shows 1.6.7.2 is the latest, and there's a 1.7 preview.

Comment: I think it's because rvm thinks it's the latest. I'll update rvm and get the latest jruby version.

Comment: Probably a good idea; I'm on rvm 1.9.2 and haven't updated for a bit. Shouldn't cause a hang in itself, though.

Comment: When I back down to 1.6.4 I may also be hanging, although I'm letting it spin for awhile yet (3min so far).

Comment: Gave up after 6 minutes. Don't see the same hang on 1.6.7. I tend to keep up on JRuby releases--the performance gains are generally substantial, and 1.6.4 is from last summer/fall-ish, IMO a bit long-in-the-tooth for JRuby.

Comment: Seems to work with jruby 1.6.7. So I'm good. Thanks.

Comment: Cool; you'll be happier w/ the performance and memory characteristics, too :)

Comment: Confirming the hang on 1.6.5. Upgrading to 1.6.7 solves it. Beware, 1.6.5 seems to be the default jruby in rvm.

Comment: @DaveNewton - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn Yours is fine :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

Upgrading to 1.6.7 solves the hang, confirmed by original poster ([Moiz Raja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420504/moiz-raja)). Hang itself confirmed by multiple parties on 1.6.4 ([Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton)) and 1.6.5 ([febeling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326840/febeling)).